# Listing all UTXOs spend by a script as well as the public key it came from

Tags: script-addresses, public-key

How do I list all Utxos that is in my script as well as the public key addresses that it came from.I am using the result as a parameter for a different function.I want to know if a public key address has already send a transaction to this script , if they have then do something , and if they have not then do something else.

Comment: Scripts do not spend utxos, transactions do. Do you mean all outputs that belong to the script at any given time?, including or excluding current unsuspended outputs?

Comment: Yep, like outputs that belong to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry can you please be more specific?

what exactly do you mean "ist all Utxos that were consumed by my script " ?

do you need a list of UTXOs for a specific address?
and additionally, do you need the address from the sender of this UTXOs?

if yes, please see below.

find all UTXOs

```
fullUtxo=/fullUtxo.out
myAddr=addr1qljkdlgamadjnlh8xmgxln4535kj5j3lgl9mawrr99nkrt2meqa2z
cardano-cli query utxo --address $myAddr --mainnet > $fullUtxo
```

find sender

```
        in_addr=$(curl -H 'project_id: MainnetBlockfrostProjectNameID' https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/txs/${tx_hash}/utxos | jq '.inputs' | jq '.[0]' | jq '.address' | sed 's/^.//;s/.$//')
```

if that helps you, would be great if you vote for my answer and give me some credits :)

have a nice day mate,
pool operator for TTS17

Comment: Yep, i wanted a list of UTXOs for a specific address and the address from the sender of this UTXOs.How can i also get the amount of times an address has send UTXOs to a script.

Comment: i dont understand what is your goal, because either i need to sell / send something to everyone for each transaction..... or i can send back tokens to many addresses ,who sent transactions, in the same transaction i send. - - - - if you want to know "how many times " of something, you can create a txt file with one line for each transaction and then execute this commands to find the number of lines "wc -l fileName.txt"   -#-#-#-#-

Comment: I want to see how many times an address has send UTXOs to a script. I am going to use that value as parameters for the script. I want to create a logic like if this public address has send UTXOs to this script once before , something happens.

Comment: like i said, i would add create a new file txt will all the tx you have currently "echo ${tx_in} >> $txsin" and better for your case, add tx there based on the sender....here you can see what i do, maybe related... if that helps you